# How do you get the value for select-option in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I tried using onChange, onClick, and ref and none of those would work to give me the value of the option I selected

```
<select ref={input => { this.handleInput(input.value) } }>
    <option value="1">Blah</option>
    <option value="2">Blah2</option>
    <option value="3">Blah3</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, input.value is showing me undefined. I don't know however else to get the option value, even changing ref to onChange and onClick didn't work

Comment: Why not use `onChange` and use the first argument `e`, then access `e.target.value`?

Comment: @Li357 That worked, thank you! I didn't know you can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `onChange` like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      result: ''
    };
  }
  
  handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      result: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <select onClick={this.handleSelectChange}>
          <option value="1">Blah</option>
          <option value="2">Blah2</option>
          <option value="3">Blah3</option>
      </select>
      {this.state.result}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: I change onClick to onChange. But I got nothing for the first select?. The 2nd and so on is ok

Comment: @SulungNugroho I think you have to add [name] attr to your selects tags to define them